# mysql with c++, my_thread_global_end

Tags: c++, mysql

I wrote a class to connect to mysql database with cppconn api. For each thread, I create such an object. Then I got that error.

I googled it. They say mysql_thread_end will solve the problem. 
But in my library, I do not have this function.

Anybody knows?

Thanks.

Below is the concerned code -

```
MyDatabaseWriter(const string& host,
                 const string& user,
                 const string& password,
                 const string& database) {
  driver_ = get_driver_instance();
  connection_ = driver_->connect(host, user, password);
  connection_->setSchema(database);
}
```

Comment: how are you calling this function?

Comment: I edited it in my question.

Comment: Which error are you referring to? Is connection_ shared between threads or it is per thread?

Comment: I create a few thread. in each thread, I create one object of this class. when the program exits, it says my_thread_global_end: 7 thread does not exit.  I googled it. It seems that the mysql instance created in my threads are not destroyed.